# Django and Vue - Vue variable in Django Tag

Tags: django, vue.js, django-templates

On a **Django-Html Template** I need to render this line of code:

```
<form action="{% url 'meal:submit_comment_rating' meal_id=meal.id comment_id=[[ comment.comment_id ]] %}" method="post">
```

Inside of a Vue for-loop:

```
<div v-for="comment in comments" id="comment_[[ comment.pk ]]">
  ...
</div>
```

Where `[[ comment.comment_id ]]` is replaced with the corresponding Vue variable:

```
meal_comments_sort = new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '#meal_comments_section',
  data: {
    comments: [
      {
        "meal_id":1,
        "user_id":1,
        "username":"admin",
        "comment_id":1,
        "comment_type":"mealcomment",
        "date":"2020-09-01T14:18:24.563Z",
        "content":"time for comment",
        "rating":-1
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

As-is I receive the Django error `Could not parse the remainder: '[[' from '[['` which I expected, but cannot find a work-around for.

**What is the best way to do this?**

I have tried wrapping the `[[ comment.comment_id ]]` variable in `{% verbatim %}` tags, but it does not help (probably because that's not how those tags are supposed to be used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I have come to is to replace the Django URL resolution tag with a static url that contains Vue variables:

```
<form :action="'/meal/{{ meal.pk }}/rate/comment/' + comment.comment_id + '/'" method="post">
```

If there is a better way to do this, I'd still prefer to use them.

Comment: An alternative format for the action label: ``:action="`/meal/{{ meal.pk }}/rate/comment/${comment.comment_id}/`"``

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem:

On click, the following a-tag must redirect to a new url based on the value of the vue-variable result.id:

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' [[result.id]] %}" id="link">Go to Page</a>
```

---

To start, the following a-tag would redirect to "/tools/browse/tools/7" if the current url is "/tools/browse/".

```
<a href="/tools/[[ result.id ]]" id="link">Go to Page</a>
```

But this is not what we want!

---

I solved this by calling a javascript function in vue that redirects to the url:

1. make the url tag for some arbitrary parameter available in javascript:

   ```
   {% url 'tools:detail' 9999 as the_url%}
   {{ the_url|json_script:"result_id"}}
   {% endblock %}
   ```

   (I choose the value 9999 as it will never occur as a real url path.
   Yes I know this is not ideal and very bad style! plz comment if you know a better way!)
2. load the varibale into the js-script:

   ```
   const result_id = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('result_id').textContent);
   ```

   (result_id now has the value "/tools/9999/")
3. In vue define a method called "redirect_vue":

   ```
   methods: {
        redirect_vue: function (id) {
            window.location = your_base_url + result_id.split("9999")[0] + id
        }
   }
   ```

   This takes the "/tools/" of the "/tools/9999/" and appends the right id. The result for "redirect_vue(7)" is "http://127.0.0.1/tools/7" with "your_base_url=http://127.0.0.1".

---

So if the following a-tag is clicked, it will redirect to the right url, which is "http://127.0.0.1/tools/7".

```
<a @click="redirect_vue(result.id)" id="link">Go to Page</a>
```